# Error with repository injection in kafka consumer class

Tags: spring-boot, circular-dependency

Im trying to run a simple spring boot application that just takes a message from kafka and saves in a db2 database.

The problem comes up when im trying to inject my repository in the consumer class!

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConsumer {


    private PortalOneRepository portalOneRepository;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topicout")
    public void consumeEventHubMessage(String consumerMessage) {
        log.info("Received message from kafka queue: {}", consumerMessage);

        //Convert string message to java object
        try {
            DocumentONE[] documentOne = objectMapper.readValue(consumerMessage, DocumentONE[].class);
            //Salvar cada mensagem no db2
            portalOneRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(documentOne));

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Error receiving message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PortalOneRepository extends JpaRepository<DocumentONE, Long> {
}
```

So after run it shows the following error message:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in
> br.examplestream.eventhub.KafkaConsumer required a
> bean of type
> 'br.examplestream.repository.PortalOneRepository'
> that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'br.examplestream.repository.PortalOneRepository' in
> your configuration.

I tried the config solution class but it shows a cyclic dependency injection problem:

```
> ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   kafkaConsumer defined in file [Z:\Users\romulo.domingos\IdeaProjects\portal-one-stream\target\classes\br\examplestream\eventhub\KafkaConsumer.class]
┌─────┐
|  getPortalOneRepository defined in class path resource [br/examplestream/config/PortalOneConfig.class]
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

This is the config class that i´ve tried :

```
@Configuration
public class PortalOneConfig {
    
    private PortalOneRepository portalOneRepository;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public PortalOneRepository getPortalOneRepository(){
        return context.getBean(PortalOneRepository.class);
        
    }
   
}
```

What is the correct way to inject my repository into my consumer class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The problem is caused by a property in application.yml file

```
autoconfigure: delete:

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

[image]

After removing the application starts to run normally again.